# MERN stack Password Reset doesn't work on frontend (Postman works perfectly fine)

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, proxy, axios

I built a login functionality for my react app and also included a password reset option. Register, login and logout work fine but the password request gives me the following error after receiving the reset email and clicking on reset after choosing a new password.

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

This is my auth.js controller in the backend:

```
const crypto = require('crypto');
const User = require('../dbmodels/User');
const ErrorResponse = require("../utils/errorResponse");
const sendEmail = require('../utils/sendEmail');

//Register User
exports.register = async (req, res, next) => {
    const{ username, email, password } = req.body;

    try{
        const user = await User.create({
            username, 
            email, 
            password,
        });

      sendToken(user, 201, res);
    } catch (error) {
        next(error);
    }
};

// Login User
exports.login = async (req, res, next) => {
    const {email, password} = req.body;

    //Check if email and password are provided
    if(!email || !password) {
       return next(new ErrorResponse("Please provide an email and password", 400)); 
    }

    //Check if user exists by email
    try {
        const user = await User.findOne({email}).select("+password");

        if(!user) {
            return next(new ErrorResponse("Invalid Credentials", 401)); 
        }
    // Check if passwords match 
    const isMatch = await user.matchPasswords(password);

    if(!isMatch) {
        return next(new ErrorResponse("Invalid Credentials", 401)); 
        }

        sendToken(user, 200, res);
    } catch (error) {
        res.status(500).json({ success: false, error: error.message });
    }
};

//Forgot Password Initialization
exports.forgotpassword = async (req, res, next) => {
   //Check if user exists and send email 
    const {email} = req.body;

   try {
    const user = await User.findOne({ email });

    if(!user) {
        return next(new ErrorResponse("Email could not be sent", 404))
    }

    //Reset Token and add to database (hashed)
    const resetToken = user.getResetPasswordToken();

    await user.save();

    //Create reset url to email 
    const resetUrl = `http://localhost:3000/passwordreset/${resetToken}`;

    const message = `
        <h1>You have requested a password reset</h1>
        <p>Please go to this link to reset your password</p>
        <a href=${resetUrl} clicktracking=off>${resetUrl}</a>
    `

    try { 
        await sendEmail({
            to: user.email,
            subject: "Password Reset Request",
            text: message,
        });

        res.status(200).json({success: true, data: "Email Sent"});
    } catch (error) {
        user.resetResetPasswordToken = undefined;
        user.resetPasswordExpire = undefined;

        await user.save();

        return next(new ErrorResponse("Email could not be sent", 500));
    }

   } catch (error) {
    next(error);
   }
};

//Reset Token is created based on request from forgot Password
exports.resetpassword = async (req, res, next) => {
    const resetPasswordToken = crypto.createHash("sha256").update(req.params.resetToken).digest
    ("hex");

    try {
        const user = await User.findOne({
            resetPasswordToken,
            resetPasswordExpire: { $gt: Date.now()},
        });

        if(!user) {
            return next(new ErrorResponse("Invalid Reset Token", 400))
        };

        user.password = req.body.password;
        user.resetPasswordToken = undefined;
        user.resetPasswordExpire = undefined;

        await user.save();

        res.status(201).json({
            success: true,
            data: "Password Reset Success",
        });
    } catch (error) {
        next(error);
    };
};

const sendToken = (user, statusCode, res) => {
    const token = user.getSignedToken();
    res.status(statusCode).json({ success: true, token });
};
```

This is my ResetPasswordScreen.js in the frontend

```
//Reset Token is created based on request from forgot Password
exports.resetpassword = async (req, res, next) => {
    const resetPasswordToken = crypto.createHash("sha256").update(req.params.resetToken).digest
    ("hex");

    try {
        const user = await User.findOne({
            resetPasswordToken,
            resetPasswordExpire: { $gt: Date.now()},
        });

        if(!user) {
            return next(new ErrorResponse("Invalid Reset Token", 400))
        };

        user.password = req.body.password;
        user.resetPasswordToken = undefined;
        user.resetPasswordExpire = undefined;

        await user.save();

        res.status(201).json({
            success: true,
            data: "Password Reset Success",
        });
    } catch (error) {
        next(error);
    };
};

const sendToken = (user, statusCode, res) => {
    const token = user.getSignedToken();
    res.status(statusCode).json({ success: true, token });
};
```

My server runs on Port 3001 and the frontend is on 3000.
Also I have a proxy in the frontend package.json saying:

```
 "proxy": "http://localhost:3001",
```

and in my config.env I declared:

```
PORT=3001
```